# Run Function when Combobox Value Change gives error

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox

I am trying to display data from DB when value in combobox changes, but I am getting

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

at  `projectName = Integer.Parse(ComboBox1.ValueMember)`

**Here is my code**

```
Public Class Total_Amount_Report

    Private Sub Total_Amount_Report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        sql = "SELECT SUM([Total Amount]) as totalAmount FROM pt_funds"



        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "TotalAmounts")
        ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables("TotalAmounts")
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Project Name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"



    End Sub

    Private Sub Combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        Dim projectName As Integer
        Dim sql2 As String

        projectName = Integer.Parse(ComboBox1.ValueMember)

        sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pt_funds WHERE ID=" & projectName & " "
        Dim da1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, con)
        da1.Fill(ds, "ProjectAmount")
        Label3.Text = ds.Tables("ProjectAmount").Rows(0).Item("Total Amount")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert the String digit into integer?  If so:

```
projectName = CInt(ComboBox1.ValueMember)
```

I believe Integer.Parse is for VB.net not VBA

Comment: I am using visual basic 2008 which I guess is .net and Integer.parse functions works pretty fine my other code

Comment: Oh ok you are looking at .net indeed, you might want to change your tag so people from .net can helps you with it

Answer (score 0):

It isn't `ComboBox1.ValueMember` that you get the value from, it's `ComboBox1.SelectedValue`. It comes back as an `Object`, so `CInt` is the easiest way to get the integer value from it.

To demonstrate, I put a ComboBox on a new Windows Form and used the following code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim dt As DataTable

    Sub FillCB()
        dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Project Name", .DataType = Type.GetType("System.String")})
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "ID", .DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32")})

        Dim projNames As New List(Of String) From {"A", "B", "C"}
        Dim projIds As New List(Of Integer) From {17, 19, 25}

        For i = 0 To projNames.Count - 1
            Dim nr = dt.NewRow
            nr.Item(0) = projNames(i)
            nr.Item(1) = projIds(i)
            dt.Rows.Add(nr)
        Next

        ' remove the SelectedIndexChanged temporarily as it interferes
        RemoveHandler ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Project Name"
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"

        AddHandler ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim cb = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        If cb.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim projectID As Integer = CInt(cb.SelectedValue)
            MsgBox(projectID.ToString())
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillCB()

    End Sub


End Class
```